# BURN-Free and DVD burn quality

Tags: dvd, burning, dvd-burning

BURN-Free is the generic name of a feature some DVD burners have which helps avoid issues that result from a buffer underrun during burning. The feature is turned on by default, but is very rarely needed on modern systems unless they're under very heavy load. According to [`wodim(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wodim):

> The BURN-Free feature is enabled by default if the drive supports it. However, use of BURN-Free may cause decreased burning quality. Therefore it can be useful to disable it for certain purposes, eg. when creating a master copy for mass CD production.

I can't find any information about this. In what way does BURN-Free decrease burning quality?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_recording_technologies#Buffer_underrun_protection

Comment: See the paragraph mentioning "small gap".

Comment: Not sure. I imagine it would require error correction to "resolve" those gaps because the reader won't know that it isn't part of the data otherwise. Even if it doesn't, it's still deteriorate the "quality" (as in, like a black spot on a white dish; you can still use the dish without any problem, but it's still a dish of bad quality)

Comment: Not sure what that (not intrinsic properties) was supposed to mean. Say a gap is 1-bit wide, and *each* gap causes one bit of "garbage data" injected at a random point to the original data track, that is for sure lower quality. (You can try to picture/imagine what it would be like if it's of "sub-bit" width -- it's actually worse since every bit of subsequent burning is "affected" / (slightly) defected.)

Comment: Well, have you thought of how though? How can a drive know that it's a gap that should be skipped, but not a bit/part of a continuous data track? Besides, the fact that it's enabled does NOT imply it will ever be *in effect* in a burn.

Comment: Also, let say there are three possible "states" of every bit of a disc: 1, 0 and "unwritten". One can say a track that has even just one "unwritten" bit is "imperfect" and hence of "inferior" quality. The thing is "quality" is more or less subjective anyway, like some people instead consider "as long as it works" "perfect", let alone what "works" is even more subjective...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126493/discussion-between-forest-and-tom-yan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand this now, based on a conversation I had in the comments on the question and several patent descriptions. It appears that these buffer underrun prevention technologies all work by the same general principle. The drive firmware detects when the drive buffer is running low and subsequently shuts down the laser. When the drive buffer is filled again, it waits until the laser is positioned over the area where the burn stopped before turning it back on and resuming.

A description of [RICOH JustLink](https://web.archive.org/web/20071117015804/http://www.ricoh.com/drive/asia/justlink/j_06.html):

> With JustLink recording, the gap between successive data writes is extremely small (less than 2 µm at 12x spped). This is achieved by using very high-definition link processing. Naturally, there is no affect on data after error correction (C1 correction, C2 correction), because with a gap of less than 2 microns even increases in error rate before error correction processing are negligible.
>
> Assuming that writing speed will increase in the future, buffer underrun error prevention technologies will become indispensable. With a 24 x writing speed for instance, JustLink would leave a patch of only 4 microns, well within the margin for error. This means JustLink has the scope and flexibility to cope with any future writing speed.
>
> [image: RICOH JustLink]
>
> The link section from RICOH JustLink, being extremely small at less than 2 µm, doesn't affect reading quality.

Other technologies, such as [Yamaha SafeBurn](https://web.archive.org/web/20030202143138/http://www.yamaha.ca/computer/cp_safeburn.asp), work in much the same way.

Because of the precise timing involved, a gap of under 2 µm may be created. The faster the disc write speed, the larger the gap. Some disc readers have trouble with larger gaps and that may reduce the reliability of reading such discs. It appears that this is only an issue if a buffer underrun *occurs* and protection kicks in. If it does not occur, then the disc is burned as if `driveropts=noburnfree` was passed to `wodim`. Burn quality (what they really mean is "compatibility") is only reduced if gaps are present and they are large enough that the drive reading the disc later stumbles on them.